# How do I publish a Power Point Presentation that is High Quality and no lag on the Web?

Tags: website, microsoft-powerpoint, presentations

I have a ~22MB Power Point Presentation (2007) that I need to be presented on a website for viewing.

The file contains audio over several slides and some embedded images.  What is the best practices or best way to present the presentation so it gets delivered the quickest and best quality to users?

Some ideas I've thought of are:

- Somehow compress the file (.wav audio files, images) into a smaller presentation and save it as a Power Point Show (pps) so users can download it and use the free Power Point viewer?
- Convert it to video format (.avi) or something and stream it off the web? (Hopefully freeware)
- Save it as a web page? (but then it's only viewable in IE I believe)

Comment: Does it need to be live (e.g. everyone viewing the same thing at the same time), or just a file that can be viewed when the user wants?

Comment: @Connor, the latter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan on doing this often, you may want to consider upgrading to Office 2010. It has two new features which are prefect for what you are doing.

One feature allows you to export the presentation as a video file, complete with slide transitions and sounds etc. This can then be played anywhere and it will look the same (removes problems of incompatibility when people have older versions of PowerPoint). This file can easily be hosted on the internet for people to download and view.

The other new feature is the ability to broadcast your presentation. This basically give you a link which you give to people who then connect and watch the presentation live as you go through it. You can find out more here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/powerpoint/share-presentations-painlessly-with-broadcast-slide-show-HA101792302.aspx?CTT=3.

However, the easiest way to do this with Office 2007 is probably to just make the presentation available on the internet for people to download and view. 22mb is quite big for a presentation, but it will only take a few seconds to download so it's not really an issue. Unless it is a very complex presentation, it should open fine in Office 2003, so there should be no problems.

Comment: thanks, will checkout that 2010 feature of converting to video, and see if we have a license for that

Comment: In the end, I tried the 2010 conversion to .WMV and the presentation lost a bit of quality in color (bit faded) and the timings of the slides/audio were off a bit. I could have played with the original perhaps to get better sync of audio/slide transitions. Anyways, I ended up compressing the .WAV audio to .MP3 and re-added it and compressed the pictures into a 350KB ppsx file. Much faster to download :)